# call requires api level 9 (current min is 7) java.text.normalizer#normalize

Tags: java, android

I finished this game a month ago, and everything worked fine until today. I get error on line:

```
odgovorNormalized = Normalizer.normalize(konResenje, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```

If I go to manifest file and change API level to anything, even to 6, I don't get error anymore. Until I change something in my code.

I've just remembered that I changed encoding of my project to Latin today. I don't know if that has anything to do with this.

Everything worked fine until today.

Comment: Well changing the API level to *6* won't help when the method was introduced in API level 9, surely...

Comment: I know that...I change it just to check my theory. And it worked fine until today.

Comment: Well try to change it to *9* instead of 6. Then it should be fine. The documentation clearly shows that it's only available in API level 9. I suspect when it was working you had an API level of 9 or higher.

Comment: Changing your minimum to 9 will stop the error, but no users with anything below 9 will be able to see your app in the Play store. Your target API, on the other hand, should always be the most current one (18 for now).

Answer (score 6):

The error is picked up by the static code analysis tools. Yes, it will compile, Yes, it will run. Yes, it will crash during runtime on any device with API < 9.

The proper thing to do is switch on the API:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        /* Use Normalizer normally */
    } else {
        /* Fall back on some default behavior */
    }
```

You can suppress errors like this, but always make sure you've fixed them first:

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void methodThatUsesNewAPI() {}
```